# CSS - how to set up background: position for 2 images beneath it for hover effect?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, background-position

I have two images in one - width is 16px, height is 24px (so each images is 16x12 px).
I would like to display first the upper image - I am doing it this way:

```
background: url('image.png') left 0px top 12px  no-repeat;
```

This works well.
But now when I hover them menu item, I would like to hide the upper image and instead of that display the one beneath - and this is what I don't know how to set up. I've tried:

```
background: url('image.png') left 0px top 0px bottom 12px  no-repeat;
```

or

```
background: url('image.png') left 0px bottom 12px  no-repeat;
```

But without any success.

Every advice will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.menuclass:hover {
     background: url('image.png')  0px -12px no-repeat;
}
```

to make this more clear , I normally type it as this

```
.menuClass:hover {
     background: url('image.png');
     background-position: 0 -12px;
     bacakground-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

The coordinates of your sprite are as follows

0 0 is the top left.

-16px 0 is the top right

-16px -24px is the bottom right

0 -24px is the bottom left

So to get the second(bottom) image ,you just use 0 -16px

0 is saying your on the very left side of the sprite. And then -16px is saying you want to start at -16px from the top.

Comment: But this is when are images next to each other, right? I have images underneath each other

Comment: It's for either. Sprites can also have images that are side by side and above and below eachother and anything inbetween.

Answer (score 0):

To make a hover button work well like this, specifically size the element to contain a single image, and then *only* override `background-position` to offset the background mapping. It takes 2 parameters - an X offset and a Y offset. To push the background *up* you need to offset the Y value *negatively* to put it 'above' the image:

```
.menuClass:hover {
    background-position:0 -24px;
}
```

[Sample provided here](http://jsfiddle.net/Curry/STnV7/2/).